# Forçar o R a manter a ordem dos valores numéricos de uma variável no gráfico de barras no ggplot2

Tags: r, classificação, ggplot2, gráfico

O ggplot está colocando as barras em ordem diferente daquela dos valores numéricos da variável "Prev", dá para ver isso rapidamente olhando os *labels* das barras. Gostaria que as barras do gráfico ficassem na mesma ordem dos valores do objeto "Prev". Acho que deve-se forçar o R a manter a ordem desejada para valores numéricos como se faz com fatores usando o pacote *forcats*.

Veja: os 5 primeiros valores em "Prev" devem corresponder às 5 primeiras barras de Outcome "Dep" na "Fase" **A** e assim por diante.... e os 5 últimos valores em "Prev" devem corresponder às 5 últimas barras de Outcome "Tes" na "Fase" **T**. E esses valores devem ser acompahandos pelos respectivos valores das barras de erros que já estão na ordem correta nos vetores low e high.

```
#Pacotes
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

# Vetores
Fase <- c(rep(c("A"), 15), rep(c("T"), 15))
Outcome<- c(rep(c("Dep", "Axy", "Tes"), 2))
Score <- c(rep(c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Extremely severe"), 6))
Prev <- c(12, 23, 24, 41, 56, 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5, 12, 23, 24, 41, 56, 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5, 12, 23, 24, 41, 56, 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5)
low = c(9, 17, 21, 38, 53, 2.7, 6, 50, 16, 20.7, 9, 19, 20, 39, 52, 3.5, 6.7, 48, 18, 22, 8.9, 15, 19.7, 38, 50, 4, 7, 52, 21, 21.9)
high = c(16, 25, 27, 45, 59, 7.8, 10, 59, 27, 27.3, 16, 27, 26, 43, 59, 9, 11, 58, 25, 29, 17, 25.5, 27, 44, 58, 8.5, 10.8, 57, 25.6, 26.7)
df <- data.frame(Fase = as.factor(Fase), Outcome = factor(Outcome), Score = as.factor(Score), Prev, low, high)

#Ordem desejada para fatores
ordem_score <- c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Extremely severe")
ordem_outcome <- c("Dep", "Axy", "Tes")

#Gráfico
df %>% 
  mutate(
    Score = fct_relevel(Score,ordem_score),
    Outcome = fct_relevel(Outcome,ordem_outcome)
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Outcome, y=Prev, fill=Score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = .8, color="black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= low, ymax= high), width = 0.3,
                position= position_dodge(width=.8)) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .4, end = .9) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.6, size = 14, color = "red")) +
  ggtitle("") +
  geom_text(label=round(Prev, 2), position= position_dodge(width=.8), vjust= -.20) +
  facet_wrap(~Fase)
```

Comment: Não percebi o voto para baixo, a pergunta tem dados, código e uma dúvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema do `fct_relevel` pode ser resolvido logo quando a base é criada. Os fatores devem ser criados com as ordens finais, uma vez que só essa ordem é necessária.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Vetores

# Ordem desejada para fatores
ordem_score <- c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Extremely severe")
ordem_outcome <- c("Dep", "Axy", "Tes")

# Fatores
Outcome <- rep(ordem_outcome, 10)
Outcome <- factor(Outcome, levels = ordem_outcome)
Score <- rep(ordem_score, 6)
Score <- factor(Score, levels = ordem_score)
Fase <- rep(c("A", "T"), each = 15)
Fase <- factor(Fase, levels = c("A", "T"))

# Vetores numéricos
Prev <- c(12, 23, 24, 41, 56, 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5, 12, 23, 24, 41, 56, 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5, 12, 23, 24, 41, 56, 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5)
low <- c(9, 17, 21, 38, 53, 2.7, 6, 50, 16, 20.7, 9, 19, 20, 39, 52, 3.5, 6.7, 48, 18, 22, 8.9, 15, 19.7, 38, 50, 4, 7, 52, 21, 21.9)
high <- c(16, 25, 27, 45, 59, 7.8, 10, 59, 27, 27.3, 16, 27, 26, 43, 59, 9, 11, 58, 25, 29, 17, 25.5, 27, 44, 58, 8.5, 10.8, 57, 25.6, 26.7)
```

Agora os valores de `Prev` vão corresponder à ordem das barras, que segue a ordem dos 3 fatores criados acima.

```
# Ordenar
i <- order(Fase, Outcome, Score)
Prev <- Prev[i]
low <- low[i]
high <- high[i]

# Tabela
df <- data.frame(Fase, Outcome, Score, Prev, low, high)
```

---

### Os gráficos.

Vou traçar 3 gráficos, para mostrar como penso que estes dados devem ser mostrados.
O gráfico que penso ser o melhor é o último. O primeiro tem as barras de erro em cima do texto e o segundo tem barras pouco largas e o texto por vezes fica em cima das barras dos lados esquerdo e direito.

---

### Gráfico 1

```
# Gráfico 1
ggplot(df, aes(x = Outcome, y = Prev, fill = Score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.8, color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= low, ymax= high), width = 0.3,
                position= position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Prev, 2)),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
             vjust = -0.20) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.4, end = 0.9) +
  ggtitle("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.6, size = 14, color = "red")) +
  facet_wrap(~ Fase)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se pode ver as barras de erro estão a tapar parte do texto em várias barras.

---

### Gráfico 2

```
# Gráfico 2
ggplot(df, aes(x = Outcome, y = Prev, fill = Score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.8, color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Prev, 2)),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
            vjust = -0.20) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.4, end = 0.9) +
  ggtitle("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.6, size = 14, color = "red")) +
  facet_wrap(~ Fase)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora parece mais legível mas certos números, por exemplo com decimais, estão a passar para outras barras. Isso acontece logo no painel `A`, grupo `Axy`, com os números 8.9 e 24.5. E os números entre barras têm um aspeto muito apertado, a tocarem nas barras dos lados.

---

### Gráfico 3

O problema do 2º gráfico pode ser resolvido mudando para gráficos mais largos, ou seja, um em cima do outro. Para isso vou usar o `facet_grid` e vai ser preciso dar um pouco mais de espaço no eixo dos y.

```
y_max <- max(df$Prev)
y_lims <- range(pretty(c(0, y_max)))

# Gráfico 3
ggplot(df, aes(x = Outcome, y = Prev, fill = Score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.8, color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Prev, 2)),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
            vjust = -0.20) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.4, end = 0.9) +
  ggtitle("") +
  ylim(y_lims) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.6, size = 14, color = "red")) +
  facet_grid(Fase ~ .)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrogado, @Rui Barradas, pelo seu tempo e ensinamentos. **Infelizmente o problema persiste**. Veja: as 5 primeiras barras (parte superior) do seu gráfico representam os valores 12, 8.9, 24, 41 e 24.5 em Prev, preciso que essas barras representem os valores 12, 23, 24, 41 e 56 em Prev. De novo, as 5 últimas barras (parte inferior) do seu gráfico representam os valores 12, 8.9, 54, 41 e 24.5 em Prev, preciso que representem os valores 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5 em Prev. Ou seja, seguir a ordem dos valores em Prev (**ordem: 12, 23, 24, 41, 56, 6.0, 8.9, ........ 56, 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5**)

Comment: @Baptista Veja agora depois da edição.

Comment: Muito obrigado, @Rui Barradas. Agora deu tudo certo! Viva o aprendizado!!!